# Javascript - Join certain values in a two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have the following 2-d array that was a result of a script copying excel sheet rows.

```
var arr = [
  ["Group", "Category", "ID", "Vendor_Name"],
  ["Network", "Policy", "ABC123", "Cisco"],
  ["Operations", "Standard", "DCF234", "Microsoft"]
]
```

How do I join specific elements so that I can get the following output:

```
var new_arr = [
  ["Group", "Category", "ID - Vendor_Name"],
  ["Network", "Policy", "ABC123 - Cisco"],
  ["Operations", "Standard", "DCF234 - Microsoft"]
]
```

Comment: What are all those variables in you array? And what is the result of `ID - Vendor_Name` supposed to be?

Comment: What does `ID - Vendor_Name` mean? Is it a subtraction or a concatenation? Are the elements arrays (as in your example) or actually objects?

Comment: Are those supposed to be arrays of strings?

Comment: @Adi: it's concatenation. I'm looking to shorten the array on the 2nd and 3rd elements with the dash "-"

Comment: We have nowhere near enough information to answer your question; can you please read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, then [edit] your question with enough - relevant - code that we can reproduce your problem? Further, you need to show your current best attempt in order that we can show where the mistake(s) might be.

Comment: Are those actually strings?

Comment: @Adi: I have updated the post. Yes they are strings (cells) from an excel sheet

Comment: @DavidThomas: Sorry for the unclear question. New to the forum after a while away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided below three answers:

- one functional solution for fixed length inner arrays (only 4 elements)
- one functional solution for variable length inner arrays (it works if the last two elements are the ID and the vendor name)
- one classic solution, with a simple for and array operations

Cheers!

```js
let arr = [
  ['Group', 'Category', 'ID', 'Vendor_Name'],
  ['Network', 'Policy', 'ABC123', 'Cisco'],
  ['Operations', 'Standard', 'DCF234', 'Microsoft']]

// For fixed length (functional)
let conv1 = arr.map(e => e.slice(0, 2).concat(e[2] + '-' + e[3]))
console.log(conv1)

// Variable length (functional)
let conv2 = arr.map(e => {
  let last = e.length - 1;
  let prev = last - 1;
  return e.slice(0, prev).concat(e[prev] + '-' + e[last]);
});

console.log(conv2)

// Classic
let conv3 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    let currElem = Array.from(arr[i]);
    let currLen = currElem.length;
    
    currElem[currLen - 2] += "-" + currElem[currLen - 1];
    currElem.pop();
    conv3.push(currElem);
}

console.log(conv3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this mate.**

```js
let arr = [
  ['Group', 'Category', 'ID', 'Vendor_Name'],
  ['Network', 'Policy', 'ABC123', 'Cisco'],
  ['Operations', 'Standard', 'DCF234', 'Microsoft']
]

let op = arr.map(e=>{
  return e.slice(0,2).concat(e[2]+ ' - '+e[3])
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: @Mikado09  you can up vote if it helped you :p anyways happy to help :)